# coleção datable jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estou com uma duvida em jsf, tenho uma coleção no meu bean List,estou printando ela em um datable, porem no meu objeto Profissional tenho uma coleção de serviços, queria printar a coleção de serviços que ele atua também em um dataTable, como faço isso?!

Answer (score 0):

Faz duas table para printar o list profissional e outra para printar a collection de servicos. Na table profissional coloque um command button, que quando pressionado passa o objeto para bean e renderiza o serviços desse profissional.
Tem algo parecido no showcase do primefaces, dá uma olhada na primeira table desse link: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml

Comment: vou tentar explicar certinho.
eu tenho uma classe Profisisonal no qual tem uma coleção de de serviços que ele presta, na view eu tenho um datable tenho as colunas que printa os atributos do profissional(nome,endereco,tel) porem em uma coluna da datable queria colocar um commandbutton no que for clicado recuperar o objeto profisisonal e printar a lista de serviços que ele presta, tentei me basear nesse exemplo citado acima, mas ele da overflow na hora de printar a coleção, deve ser por que ele não iterando....